# How to invoke map() from a ProductIterator (Tuple)

Tags: scala

Given following placeholder logging method:

```
def testshow(value: Any) = value.toString
```

In the following code snippet:

```
  case t : Product =>
    t.productIterator.foreach( a => println(a.toString))
     val lst =  t.productIterator.map(a => testshow(a))
     val lst2 = t.productIterator.map(_.toString)
      lst.mkString("(",",",")")
      lst2.mkString("(",",",")")
```

And given an input tuple :

```
(Some(OP(_)),Some(a),1)
```

The println successfully shows entries for the given tuple.

```
Some(OP(_))
Some(a)
1
```

lst2 (with toString) says:  Non-empty iterator.  However the  list "lst" says:

```
empty iterator
```

So what is wrong with the syntax to invoke the map() method on the productIterator?

Note: if putting "toString" in place of testshow this works properly.

Update: A "self contained" snippet does work.  It is still not clear why the above code does not..

```
def testshow(value: Any) = "TestShow%s".format(value.toString)

val obj = ("abc",123,"def")
obj match {
  case t : Product =>
    t.productIterator.foreach( a => println(a.toString))
    val lst =  t.productIterator.map(a => testshow(a))
    val lst2 = t.productIterator.map(_.toString)
    println("testshow list %s".format(lst.mkString("(",",",")")))
    println("toString list %s".format(lst2.mkString("(",",",")")))
  }
```

Output:

```
abc
123
def
testshow list (**abc**,**123**,**def**)
toString list (abc,123,def)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like an Intellij Bug. I just changed the name of the "lst" variable to "lst3" and it works. I repeated the process of name/rename back/forth and it is repeatable bug. There are no other occurrences of "lst" in the entire file and in any case it was a local variable.

Answer (score 0):

Iterators can be traversed only once, then they are exhausted. Mapping an iterator produces another iterator. If you see your iterator empty, you must have forced a traversal.

```
scala> case class Foo(a: Int, b: Int)
defined class Foo

scala> Foo(1, 2).productIterator.map(_.toString)
res1: Iterator[String] = non-empty iterator
```

It *is non-empty*. Are you sure you used a fresh iterator? Because if you used the same iterator for the first `foreach` loop, then it would be empty if you tried to `map` the same iterator afterwards.

---

**Edit:** The shape of the `map` function argument has nothing to do with this:

```
def testshow(value: Any) = value.toString

case class OP(x: Any)

def test(x: Any) = x match {
  case t: Product =>
    val lst = t.productIterator.map(a => testshow(a))
    lst.mkString("(", ",", ")")
  case _ => "???"
}

test((Some(OP(_)),Some('a'),1))  // "(Some(<function1>),Some(a),1)"
```

Comment: I am updating my answer:  if I put _.toString it works. The issue is with how to define/invoke the custom method "testshow"

Comment: If the "shape" of the map iterator has nothing to do with this -- then why is the first lst empty yet the second "lst2" is non-empty?

Comment: @javadba you need to provide a fully self contained example which can be reproduced. As I have shown in my edited version, the iterator behaves absolutely correct, even with your definition of `testshow`. You are looking in the wrong spot, and I am sure this will be revealed when you boil it down to a self contained example.

Comment: i am working on that self contained script.. just did not see any way the iterator would be exhausted already.  will update post in few

Comment: Looks like an Intellij Bug. I just changed the name of the "lst" variable to "lst3" and it works. I repeated the process of name/rename back/forth and it is repeatable bug.  There are no other occurrences of "lst" in the entire file and in any case it was a local variable.